# automapper exception when add Id in ViewModel

Tags: c#, api, automapper

This is my Model in Model project

```
public class CompanyName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<CarModel> CarModels { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<CreateYear> CreateYear { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Diversity> Diversities { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<CarPrice> CarPrices { get; set; }
}
```

and this is ViewModel for that

```
public class CompanyNameVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also this is my Code for p=mapping in ViewModel Project

```
public class MiMapping:Profile
{
    public MiMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Task<CompanyName>, Task<CompanyNameVM>>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

after that for use it in Api I use this block

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyNameController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICompanyNameRepository _companyNameRepository;
    private IMapper _mapper;


    public CompanyNameController(ICompanyNameRepository companyNameRepository,IMapper mapper)
    {
        _companyNameRepository = companyNameRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCarCompanyAsync()
    {
        var cmObj = await _companyNameRepository.GetAllAsync();
        var cvvm = new List<CompanyNameVM>();

        foreach (var obj in cmObj)
        {
            cvvm.Add(_mapper.Map<CompanyNameVM>(obj));
        }
        return  Ok( cvvm);
    }
}
```

after run when I call -

`http://localhost:53199/api/companyName`

got this error

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
> Mapping types:
> Object -> CompanyNameVM
> System.Object -> MI.ViewModel.CompanyNameVM

It worked fine until I add ***Id*** in My ViewModel.
how can I resolve that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a map between `CompanyName` and `CompanyNameVM` then do it like -

```
CreateMap<CompanyName, CompanyNameVM>().ReverseMap();
```

No need to involve `Task` in mapping.

Also, no need to manually iterate over the `CompanyName` objects and map one at a time. You can simplify your controller code as -

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCarCompanyAsync()
{
    var cmObj = await _companyNameRepository.GetAllAsync(); 
    var cvvm = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompanyNameVM>>(cmObj);  
    return Ok(cvvm);
}
```

I'm assuming `_companyNameRepository.GetAllAsync()` is returning an `IEnumerable<CompanyName>` in some form.

Comment: Thanks my mistake was for add tsk in CreateMap<CompanyName, CompanyNameVM>().ReverseMap();